# Remove a :target tag

Tags: html, css

I have been using css3 and the target attribute to make an interactive menu. When i click a menubutton, i make it open the sub-menu by using the :target attribute. I simply say that when my menu point is the target, set the submeny height to auto, if its not the target, it should have a height of 0.

But now is my question: Is there an easy way to remove the target again? What i want to do, is that when i click the menu button, the submenu will show (I already made that). Then if i click the same button again, i want is to close again.

Is there a way to do this with pure css/html, or will i need to change to javascript/jquery to do this? I used css3 to avoid this so far.

Comment: Yes, I think so (or sort of); can you show the (representative/minimal) code you're using? A simple HTML and CSS reproduction of your problem, in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an absolutely positioned link to another anchor that appears in front of the link to your `:target`, and make it display only if the current `:target` works. So visually it will behave as a toggle link ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WWWX/1/)):

HTML

```
<div id="test">
    <h2>
        <a href="#test">Open me</a>
        <a href="#" class="untarget"></a>
    </h2>
    <div>
        <p>Some contents</p>
        <p>Some more contents</p>
        <p>Some more contents again</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The key part of CSS

```
h2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.untarget {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}

:target .untarget {
    display: block;
}
```

Another (and quite popular) way to implement the toggle functionality without JS is using hidden checkboxes/radio buttons and their `:checked` pseudo-class along with CSS sibling combinators. But personally I doubt if it the right way of HTML usage.

Comment: Having finally remembered that I left a comment on this question, some hours ago, I thought I'd see about posting an answer. Then I found yours, which is very similar to the way I'd've handled it ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3WWWX/2/)), so: +1 =)